# Making the CLOSE button on Modalbox Twitter bootsrap bigger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anybody know, where I can modify the close button of the Modal Box of Twitter bootstrap 3 ? It is very small and almost unclickable with tablets and phones...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```
.modal-header .close {
  font-size: 40px; //bigger
}
```

(On Firefox and Chrome you can right click on the modal close button and select 'inspect element' from the contextual menu. It shows you the HTML structure and if you click elements the CSS rules attached to them. It is very useful to debug or experiment new designs without hassle.)

Comment: Thanks... Yes it worked, I had to modify it on: bootstrap.overrides.cc

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can close the question by clicking on the check icon on the left of the answer that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
button.close
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

I would prefer not to use css like that. It's better to add extra custom class to modal button and the use css to that class.